# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n {\left(\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\right)}\right)}$

Tags: summation

Evaluate:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n {\left(\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\right)}\right)}$$
It looks like the series for $\ln(2)$ 'embedded in itself', so my guess for the value is $\ln^2(2)$. Unfortunately, this is not correct, as an estimate for the sum is $1.06269$, much greater than $\ln^2(2)\approx 0.48045$.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $S$ be given by

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k}\tag1$$

---

We can interchange the order of summation in $(1)$ and express $S$ as

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k}\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \tag2$$

whereupon switching "dummy" summation indices in $(2)$ yields

$$\begin{align}S&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k}\right)\\\\
&=\log^2(2)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k}\\\\
&=\log^2(2)-S+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\tag3
\end{align}$$

---

Using $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ in $(3)$ and solving for $S$ we find

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{S=\frac12 \log^2(2)+\frac{\pi^2}{12}}\tag 4$$

---

> **NOTE:**

The result in $(4)$ is not at all surprising given the symmetry.  We can write in general

$$\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \right)^2&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\\\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k-\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2
\end{align}$$

which becomes upon rearranging

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k=\frac12 \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \right)^2+\frac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$$

Finally, setting $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, we recover the result in $(4)$.

Comment: could you explain how the "switch" of summation works?

Comment: @DeepSea $$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n  \sum_{k=1}^n a_k=\sum_{k=1}^N a_k \sum_{n=k}^N a_n$$The entire development proceeds with our taking $N\to \infty$ as a last step.

Comment: Wow, your answer is perfect! The way the sum from 1 to n was transformed into the sum from n to infinity was really nice, and I appreciated the note that generalized the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The series is only conditionally convergent, so it's not totally obvious that changing the order of summation is valid. There is something to check.

Comment: +1. Great answer. The last identity is widely used in Statistical Physics because the cross sum can be expressed in terms of the square of a sum. This one can be written as a linear term in a gaussian integration. It allows to evaluate the sum and the whole problem is reduced to evaluate an integral in a saddle point asymptotic approach.

Comment: @julianrosen As I stated in a comment herein, the analysis can proceed with a finite sum with upper limit say $N$.  We take the limit as $N\to \infty$ at the end if the development and arrive at the result given in this posted solution.

Comment: @johnchessant You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @felixmarin Thank as always!

Comment: The interchange of double sum as you suggested in the comment is in fact: $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \left( \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{k\leq n} \right)= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{n=k}^N\right)$$ but (2) is $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^N \lim_{M\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n=k}^M$$

Comment: @i707107 The formal development can be made rigorous by proceeding as in the comment.  The limits that you have written are then shown to be equivalent.  Is that your point?

Comment: My point is that the equivalence of the limits must be justified.

Comment: @i707107 I just stated a way to justify this.  Does that suffice or do I need to show you the details?

Comment: I think you need to show the details in this case because this double sum is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: @i707107 Is this development for you?  The OP has accepted this answer and several others have up voted and commented as to its usefulness.

Comment: Yes. i really want to know how you could prove that $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{n=k}^N = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N \lim_{M\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n=k}^M $$

Comment: @i707107 $$\begin{align}
S_N&=\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \sum_{k=1}^n a_k\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\sum_{k=n}^N a_k\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \left(\sum_{k=1}^N a_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \sum_{k=1}^N a_k-\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \sum_{k=1}^na_k+\sum_{n=1}^Na_n^2\\\\\
2S_N&=\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \sum_{k=1}^N a_k+\sum_{n=1}^Na_n^2\\\\
S_N&=\frac12 \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \sum_{k=1}^N a_k+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^Na_n^2\\\\
&=\frac12 \left(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\right)^2+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^Na_n^2\\\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: @i707107 Are you worried about the "extra" component $\sum_{k=1}^N a_k \sum_{n=N+1}^M a_n$?  Clearly this approaches $0$ as $(N,M) \to \infty$ (a la Cauchy).  Do you see now?

Comment: Thank you, that development of $S_N$ works within finite sums and both sums at the end converges as $N\rightarrow \infty$. Now, it is clear to me.

Comment: In my opinion, it would have been better to start developing finite sums as in your comment and take the limit at the end.

Comment: @i707107 We now have the solution supplemented with comments, which will give future users a complete and comprehensive way forward.